# How to enable double click function on DataGridView in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I dont know how can enable double click function, when user click on the row with five columns to show values on message box this full row with five columns ?

I use MySQL db.

I have this method:

```
       private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int index = e.RowIndex;

        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Selected = true;
    }
```

and I created this method ..

```
       private void allOrders_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
    }
```

The question is ? How can I show row with all columns in MessageBox ?

Comment: How is mysql related to that?

Comment: Also you can bind double click event, the same way, as the all other events.

Comment: I click on the event double click, and I have this method:

private void allOrders_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

Comment: so, whats your problem now?

Comment: I update the question if this help for me

Comment: I don't get several parts in your code: 
1)`dataGridView1.Rows[index].Selected = true;` - why are you trying to select the cell manually?
2)Why you changing your `dataGridView1` selection mode with double click?

Comment: I want when user selected current row to show new form with fill textboxes..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156429/discussion-between-sem-and--).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

This is done by DataGridView Event. The following above code executes when the double click is occur on DataGridView.

-- You can get variety of events

1- Click on DataGridView Control

2- On properties window click on Events Tab now you can get all Events there.

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have bind your `DataGridView`'s data source from `DataTable`.
For Example:

```
private void InitDataGridView()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();        
    table.Columns.Add("1");
    table.Columns.Add("2");
    table.Columns.Add("3");
    table.Columns.Add("4");
    table.Columns.Add("5");

    table.Rows.Add("1", 2, 3, "4", 5);
    table.Rows.Add("11", 21, 31, "41", 51);
    table.Rows.Add("11", 12, 13, "14", 15);
    table.Rows.Add("21", 22, 23, "24", 25);
    table.Rows.Add("13", 32, 33, "34", 35);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Now lets see `DoubleClick()` method, for example, you can get your selected row collection into string array, then pass it to `MessageBox` or new `Form` or use it wherever you want:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]; //Get selected Row
    string[] selectedValues = new string[selectedRow.Cells.Count]; //Init string array or list, or custom object array/list

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        selectedValues[i] = selectedRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString(); //Fill your array with cell values
    }

    //Your next code goes here
}
```